# Program to run function

Tags: c

I have a question for my assignment:

> Write a function called second which takes, as parameters, an array of
>   positive integers and also an integer representing the size of the
>   array. The function returns the value of the second largest integer in
>   the array. If the largest integer in the array repeats, then the
>   second largest integer is also the largest. For example, if we have
>   {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5 }, the second largest integer is
>   5. The function should not change the contents of the array in any way. You can assume that the size of the array is at least two.

What I've done:

```
int second(const int arr[], int size)
{
    int num1,num2;
    int i;

    if(arr[0]>arr[1])
    {
        num1=arr[0];num2=arr[1];

    }
    else 
    {
        num1=arr[1];num2=arr[0];
    }

    for (i=2; i<size; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i]>num1)
        {
            num2=num1;
            num1=arr[i];
        }
        else if (arr[i] > num2)
        {
            num2=arr[i];
        }
    }

   return num2;
}
```

I have no idea how to type a program that can run the above function and display the integer '5'

Answer (score 0):

> The function should not change the contents of the array in any way.

Use a temporary `array` to perform all the operations. Simply copy the elements from the old `array` to the new temp `array`.

> Write a function called second which takes, as parameters, an array of
>   positive integers and also an integer representing the size of the
>   array

Case 1: if the array is unsorted 
You could just `sort` the elements(ascending order) and return the `second last` element.

Case 2: If the array is sorted
Just return the `second last` element.

There are lots of sorting algorithms like `quicksort` and `mergesort` which give you a better runtime but you could use `bubble` sort as well if there is no constraint on time complexity.

Additional Hint:

```
int second(const int arr[], int size)
{
  int temp[size]; //<-----use a temporary array as you're not allowed to modify the original array
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<size;i++)
         {
              //copy the elements
          }

       //sort the temp array in ascending order  

    return temp[size-2];  //<----return the second last elements       


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not looking at your function `second`. I will leave that to you as an exercise.

To run this function, you will need to make a main program which will create this array and call this function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int second(const int arr[], int size);

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,6,7};
    int N = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

    printf ("%d ", second(arr, N));
}
```

You can add your code below the code here and compile.